# Creating new columns for duplicate ids

Tags: excel, vba

I'm kind of drawing a blank here, and maybe Excel is not the best place to do this but I'm trying to create new columns in an excel sheet if the idea is changed.

Example would be like table below

| ID | Name | Date | Product | Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 01/01/2020 | Chairs | 100 |
| 2 | Joe Smith | 01/02/2020 | Chairs | 100 |
| 1 | John Smith | 01/01/2020 | Tables | 200 |
| 1 | John Smith | 01/01/2020 | Tables | 200 |
| 3 | John Smith | 01/02/2020 | Chairs | 100 |

and I want to transform it into

| ID | Name | Date | Product 1 | Value 1 | Product 2 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 01/01/2020 | Chairs | 100 | Tables | 400 |
| 2 | Joe Smith | 01/02/2020 | Chairs | 100 |  |  |
| 3 | John Smith | 01/02/2020 | Chairs | 100 |  |  |

It's basically aggregrating up based on ID and splitting the products and values into separate columns, and summing the value if id and product are the same. So for example above, John Smith has bought 2 sets of chairs and one table on the 01/01/2020 so we get two product columns and value for chairs is summed up.

Is that possible in Excel, or do I need to go back towards source data. I feel like it should be doable in VBA but my mind is drawing a blank atm.

Comment: What is your Excel version?

Comment: It's Excel for 365

Answer (score 0):

Power Query is good at data transformation. Get it done w/o any VBA code.

**Note**: The result differs slightly from your expected output.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Product", type text}, {"Val", Int64.Type}}),
    GroupRow = Table.Group(ChangeType, {"ID", "Name", "Date", "Product"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([Val]), type nullable number}}),
    PivotColumn = Table.Pivot(GroupRow, List.Distinct(GroupRow[Product]), "Product", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    PivotColumn
```

[image]